# How long can you store StarSan in its concentrated form?

Tags: starsan

I recently got back into brewing after a 5 year hiatus, and noticed that my StarSan is a little darker in color than the stuff they sell at the LHBS. The guy at the LHBS said it can lose its potency, but should be fine. I used a little bit more than I would have (not much) if it was fresh, and everything seemed normal.

Has anybody here had to store StarSan for a long period of time (2-5 years)? And if so, how did it work out?

Comment: see also this question - how long does starsan last http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-long-does-starsan-last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still using the same 32oz bottle that I bought four and a half years ago with no problems. To check for potency of the made-up solution

- ensure that the pH is below 3.5
- check that there is still some foaming when shaken

Comment: pH should be 3 or lower. See [here](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/star-san.html)

Comment: pH 3.5 is the limit - see [here](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f11/charlie-talley-five-star-chemicals-notes-brewcasts-58928/#post599059) - a transcript of the Brewing Netowrk show featuring Charlie Talley of Five Star Chemicals, where he goes into some detail about what makes StarSan effective.

Comment: Thanks! The stuff foamed wonderfully when I mixed it, so I am assuming it is still good. I'll get some litmus paper next time I am at the LHBS and test it for sure.